# i am having trouble in project

Tags: python, pandas, youtube-api

i am working on [Youtube API for Python: How to Create a Unique Data Portfolio Project](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D56_Cx36oGY)

and i always got an error message while running this code:

```
import isodate
video_df["durationSecs"]= video_df["duration"].apply(lambda x: isodate.parse_duration(x))
video_df["durationSecs"]= video_df["durationSecs"].astype("timedelta64[s]")
```

error message is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) Cell In[111], line 2
      1 import isodate
----> 2 video_df["durationSecs"]= video_df["duration"].apply(lambda x: isodate.parse_duration(x))
      3 video_df["durationSecs"]= video_df["durationSecs"].astype("timedelta64[s]")

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py:4764, in Series.apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, by_row, **kwargs)    4629 def apply(    4630     self,    4631     func: AggFuncType,    (...)    4636     **kwargs,    4637 ) -> DataFrame | Series:    4638   """    4639     Invoke function on values of Series.    4640     (...) 4755     dtype: float64    4756     """    4757     return SeriesApply(    4758         self,    4759         func,    4760       convert_dtype=convert_dtype,    4761         by_row=by_row,    4762    args=args,    4763         kwargs=kwargs,
-> 4764     ).apply()

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py:1209, in SeriesApply.apply(self)    1206     return self.apply_compat()    1208
# self.func is Callable
-> 1209 return self.apply_standard()

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py:1289, in SeriesApply.apply_standard(self)    1283 # row-wise access    1284 # apply doesn't have a `na_action` keyword and for backward compat reasons    1285 # we need to give `na_action="ignore"` for categorical data.    1286 # TODO: remove the `na_action="ignore"` when that default has been changed in    1287 #  Categorical (GH51645).    1288 action = "ignore" if isinstance(obj.dtype, CategoricalDtype) else None
-> 1289 mapped = obj._map_values(    1290     mapper=curried, na_action=action, convert=self.convert_dtype    1291 )    1293 if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], ABCSeries):    1294     # GH#43986 Need to do list(mapped) in order to get treated as nested    1295     #  See also GH#25959 regarding EA support    1296     return obj._constructor_expanddim(list(mapped), index=obj.index)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py:919, in IndexOpsMixin._map_values(self, mapper, na_action, convert)
    916 arr = self._values
    918 if isinstance(arr, ExtensionArray):
--> 919     return arr.map(mapper, na_action=na_action)
    921 return algorithms.map_array(arr, mapper, na_action=na_action, convert=convert)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/_mixins.py:80, in ravel_compat.<locals>.method(self, *args, **kwargs)
     77 @wraps(meth)
     78 def method(self, *args, **kwargs):
     79     if self.ndim == 1:
---> 80         return meth(self, *args, **kwargs)
     82     flags = self._ndarray.flags
     83     flat = self.ravel("K")

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimelike.py:723, in DatetimeLikeArrayMixin.map(self, mapper, na_action)
    719 @ravel_compat
    720 def map(self, mapper, na_action=None):
    721     from pandas import Index
--> 723     result = map_array(self, mapper, na_action=na_action)
    724     result = Index(result)
    726     if isinstance(result, ABCMultiIndex):

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py:1814, in map_array(arr, mapper, na_action, convert)    1812 values = arr.astype(object, copy=False)    1813 if na_action is None:
-> 1814     return lib.map_infer(values, mapper, convert=convert)    1815 else:    1816     return lib.map_infer_mask(    1817         values, mapper, mask=isna(values).view(np.uint8), convert=convert    1818     )

File lib.pyx:2926, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

Cell In[111], line 2, in <lambda>(x)
      1 import isodate
----> 2 video_df["durationSecs"]= video_df["duration"].apply(lambda x: isodate.parse_duration(x))
      3 video_df["durationSecs"]= video_df["durationSecs"].astype("timedelta64[s]")

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/isodate/isoduration.py:86, in parse_duration(datestring)
     58 """
     59 Parses an ISO 8601 durations into datetime.timedelta or Duration objects.
     60     (...)
     83   days set to 0.
     84 """
     85 if not isinstance(datestring, string_types):
---> 86     raise TypeError("Expecting a string %r" % datestring)
     87 match = ISO8601_PERIOD_REGEX.match(datestring)
     88 if not match:
     89     # try alternative format:

TypeError: Expecting a string Timedelta('0 days 00:00:29')
```

Comment: Please give a *descriptive* title to your question.